# Science to combine words the right way

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

Is there a "science" (or a tool/website) that allows us to combine words the right way?

For example, if I write "fixing a problem", the tool will suggest "solving a problem". Another example: "fixing an issue" -> "resolving an issue"?

I heard, once, that such a "science" (it's not grammar as far as I know) exists, but never *caught its name* (or is it *grasped its name*?).

Comment: One might argue that *Linguistics* is the science of combining words the right way. As for a tool/website - sorry, that is out of scope for EL&U.

Comment: dictionaries, thesauri etc...

Comment: The phenomenon you're talking about is sometimes called _collocation_ in linguistics.

Comment: Could you be thinking of paraphrasing ... saying in other words? https://www.google.pt/search?ei=yLVYW_mgN8GsabaIhsgO&q=english+paraphrasing+tool&oq=english+sentence+improver&gs_l=psy-ab.1.5.0i71k1l8.0.0.0.7705.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.I31V4HvGG2k

Comment: @OliverMason Absolutely.

Comment: @Lawrence I would say that linguistics is the science of *describing* (and, perhaps, trying to explain) how we combine words, and what "the right way" might mean, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of what is called [collocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation) in linguistics.

From looking at the distribution of lexical items (words) in (authentic) texts, it was observed that they are not randomly distributed, but co-occur together with a typically smallish set of other words. This is the set of collocations of a word.

Some of these collocations are part of idioms or fixed phrases, eg *rasher* pretty much always co-occurs with *bacon* -- you don't get rashers of anything else. *Rancid* would apply to gone-off dairy products, eg *rancid butter*, [but not *rancid fruit*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rancid%20fruit%2C%20rancid%20butter%2C%20rancid%20meat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crancid%20fruit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancid%20butter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancid%20meat%3B%2Cc0).

There are statistical methods to identify collocations, which usually start with the assumption that words are randomly distributed and then count co-occurrence statistics working out that they actually aren't, and those words with a higher-than-expected co-occurrence count are the collocations.

Some overlap exists with multi-word units, phrasal verbs, idioms, and fixed phrases, which arguably are all interlinked. There is also *colligation*, where you have non-lexical phenomena: the word *budge*, for example, will most likely be preceded by a negative, as in *they will not budge*. So here we have a grammatical category ('negative') rather than an actual word.

Answer (score 2):

While there can be many "wrong ways" for expressing something, there is never a single "right way."

For instance, there is nothing wrong with *fixing a problem* that some other word or phrasing would objectively correct.

Any one arrangement of words can have *many* different (and grammatical) phrasings that express the same thing.

English is at least as much an art as it is a science. While you may find some tools that suggest different words or phrasings, they may not be (and often aren't) accurate. Nor would they be definitive.

Comment: That's not the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a **thesaurus**; a book or website that suggests alternative words with the same or similar meaning. For example: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fixing

Although this doesn't give "solving" as an option, so it isn't perfect. And it only works with words, not phrases.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are thinking of paraphrase

> paraphrase
>
> ˈparəfreɪz/
>
> verb
>   1. express the meaning of (something written or spoken) using different words, especially to achieve greater clarity.
>
> "you can either quote or paraphrase literary texts"
>   synonyms:   reword, rephrase, put/express in other words, put/express in one's own words, express differently, rewrite, rescript, restate, rehash, interpret, gloss
>   "you can either quote or paraphrase literary texts"
>
> noun
>   1. a rewording of something written or spoken.
>
> "scattered here and there in the text are frank paraphrases of lines from Virgil, Cicero, and Quintilian"
>
> synonyms:  rewording, rephrasing, rewriting, rewrite, restatement, restating, rehash, rendition, rendering, version, interpretation, gloss; rareparaphrasis
>
> "this paraphrase of St Paul's words"

see [google definition here](https://www.google.com/search?q=paraphrase&oq=paraphrase&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61j0j69i60j0.6650j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

There are some paraphrasing tools, such as [paraphrase-online.com](https://www.paraphrase-online.com/), but be careful because you may need to correct grammar issues.

I paraphrased your example "fix a problem", and received "settle a issue" (sic). As you can see, it should be "settle an issue"